# Jupyter Notebook: enable vertical scrolling in code block in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running jupyter notebook in vscode and would like to scroll through the output of the code block so I can see the entire output. Is there a way to toggle on vertical scroll for jupyter notebook in vscode?

Answer (score 0):

open VSCode Setting(setting.json)，add the following three configurations.

```
"notebook.output.wordWrap": true,
"notebook.output.scrolling": true,
"notebook.output.textLineLimit": 16
```